# Inserting trend line and slider for smoothing in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking to produce a trend line for the plot within my R shiny application, along with a checkbox that allows the trend line to be smoothed using a slider. When I go to apply an "if" statement, the plot does not show up at all in my app. I have pasted the code for my ui and server down below for reference. Thanks

Ui

```
# Select whether to overlay smooth trend line
    checkboxInput(inputId = "smoother", label = strong("Overlay smooth trend line"), value = FALSE),
  
  # Display only if the smoother is checked
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.smoother == true"),
    
    sliderInput(inputId = "f", label = "Smoother span:", min = 0.01, max = 1, value = 0.67, step = 0.01,
      animate = animationOptions(interval = 100))
  ),
  
## Showcase created plot
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("scatter")),
                        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summ")),
                        tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("mtcd"))
  )
    )
)
)
```

Server

```
### Define server logic
server<-function(input,output,session) {

## Create and fill Data and Summary tabs
  output$mtcd <- renderTable({mtcd})
  output$summ <- renderPrint({summary(mtcd)})
  
## Receive data from imported file
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    read.csv(input$datafile$datapath, header = TRUE)})
  
## Create output - scatter plot
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    
    df <- datasetInput()
      
      mtc <- mtcd[ ,c(input$Asp1,input$Char)]
      mtc[,2] <- as.factor(mtc[,2])
      ggplot(data = mtc, aes(x=mtc[,1],y=mtcd$Fuel_consumption,color=mtc[,2]))+
        geom_point()+
        labs(x=colnames(mtc)[1], y= "Fuel_consumption", 
             color=colnames(mtc)[2], 
             title = paste("Scatter Plot of Fuel_consumption", "Vs", input$Asp1))
      
    # Display only if smoother is checked
      if(input$smoother){
        smooth_curve <- lowess(x = mtc[,1], y = as.numeric(mtcd$Fuel_consumption), f = input$f)
        lines(smooth_curve, col = "#E6553A", lwd = 3)}
})
}
```

#### Run the app by clicking "Run App" in upper right hand corner"

```
shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: `lines` is not a ggplot function.

Comment: @IRTFM could you please recommend a substitute function that I could use instead?

Comment: Instead of `lines` you could use `geom_line` or perhaps switch to `geom_smooth` which avoids having to compute the smoothed values manually.

Comment: @stefan is there any way I could include a slider to adjust the smoothness of either geom_line or geom_smooth, or maybe include some sort of "if" statement along with a checkbox to display either the geom_line or geom_smooth?

Comment: Sure could you a checkbox and a slider to switch between line/smooth or set the smoothing. geom_smooth uses `loess` under the hood so I would guess that there is a parameter to set the smooting to which you could pass the value of a slider.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+slider+geom_line